# c++ header file return pair type

Tags: c++

My experience with C++ is very limited so here goes.. :P

I have a header file with the following structure

```
namespace simpleDLLNS{
class simpleDLL
{
public:
void simpleCall();
pair<int, const char*> load();
};}
```

Problem is that I get the following error: error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'.
I guess my question is how does one declare a method with return type pair.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code looks OK, so I can only assume you are missing the right header and/or neglecting to specify the `std` namespace.

```
#include <utility>
namespace simpleDLLNS{
class simpleDLL
{
public:
  void simpleCall();
  std::pair<int, const char*> load();
};
}
```